# How do I return the value from a For loop in this fibonacci?

Tags: c#, return, fibonacci

How do I return the value from a For loop in this fibonacci?
Right now it just returns at ***send = 0***.
My goal is to place the values into a list in the Main method.

```
 public static int Fibo( int count) 
    {
        int i, f1 = 0, f2 = 1, send = 0;  
        for (i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            int f3 = f1 + f2; 
            f3 = send;                
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
        }
        return send;
    }
```

Comment: loop never returns value

Comment: No, assignments don't return. Your code returns at `return`, you just never assign anything to `send` other than 0.

Comment: Change method to return `IEnumerable<int>` and replace line `f3 = send;` with `yield return f3;`

Comment: what is `send`? where is it defined?

Comment: int i, f1 = 0, f2 = 1, send = 0;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return "send" you need at some point of your code to write "send = f3;"

Comment: @zx485 I disagree, this is *exactly* the problem with the code so it is, in fact, an answer to the question.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: You're right. The return value must be set somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to materialize the numbers into list, why not implement a `IEnumerable<int>` generator? The key feature is using `yield return` (return and continue doing the routine) instead of `return`.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Fibo() {
  int left = 0;
  int right = 1;

  yield return left;
  yield return right;

  while (true) {
    int result = left + right;

    // returning from a loop while keep on looping
    yield return result;

    left = right;
    right = result; 
  }
}
```

....

```
List<int> myList = Fibo().Take(10);
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I'll do some more research IEnumerable.       @CodeCaster  How are you so able to judge the amount of knowledge I'll gain from his response?

Comment: @ CodeCaster  Woah. "Won't teach you anything" and " your code is bad, use my code" are total fallacies. Maybe you're great at coding but you're certainly not great at teaching.